# The soundness of this sentence: "we evaluate the effectiveness of the/our proposed method"

Tags: sentence-usage

My question is about the soundness of the sentence:

> "we evaluate the effectiveness of the/our proposed method"

It seems that it is used in writings and is grammatically correct. However, according to my searches, it seems to me that this sentence is mostly used in the writings of non-English speakers and I could find almost no (or a very small number of) authors with names that looked like English to me that use the sentence. Is there something unusual in the sentence that prevents native speakers from using it?

Comment: It's grammatical (native speaker here).

Comment: it's not that it is not grammatical. The real question is where in a paper is it being used? "We evaluate the effectiveness of the proposed method", then, what? Also, you might want to substitute other search terms for **we**: the team, the committee, the peer review committee, etc. But don't forget to add an s to the verb.

Comment: The point is that it seems that it is used by non-native speakers in its current form (the sentence may not finish at "method" and continues). Just make a Google search with the sentence in quotes and look at the author names. Either with the or with our, although.

Comment: It is fine although it is a bit pompous outside of technical or academic writing which may be affecting your search results.

Answer (score 0):

I can so no reason why a native speaker would not use your example.

It's possible the phrasing may be slightly different

> "we ***observe*** the effectiveness of the/our proposed method"
>   "we ***demonstrate*** the effectiveness of the/our proposed method"

which would make the latter more assertive.